# Construção de Rule personalizada Sonarqube

Tags: java, plugin, analise-léxica

olá!

Estou criando um plugin no SonarQube com Rules personalizadas e como minha primeira rule, quero fazer uma validação em declarações If onde seja disparado um alarme toda vez que uma String literal entrar como parâmetro.

Estou seguindo a estrutura de exemplo que está na [documentação do software](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101), porém não consigo encontrar nenhuma documentação sobre possíveis alternativas na construção de Rules.

Para testar, estou usando um código de uma tela do Android DIVA:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HardcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hardcode);
    }

    public void access(View view) {
        EditText hckey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hcKey);

        if (hckey.getText().toString().equals("vendorsecretkey")) { // Noncompliant
            Toast.makeText(this, "Access granted! See you on the other side :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Access denied! See you in hell :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Visto isso, a comparação está sendo feita por minha Rule no seguinte trecho:

```
    @Override
  public void visitNode(Tree tree){
    IfStatementTree ifStatement = (IfStatementTree) tree;
    ifStatement.condition().kind();
    if (ifStatement.condition().kind() == (Kind.STRING_LITERAL)){
        reportIssue(ifStatement.ifKeyword(), "Comparação if sendo feita com string literal!");
    }
  }
```

O problema está ocorrendo devido aos fatores que estão sendo utilizados para comparação da regra, mas não encontro nenhum método ou atributo que possa me ajudar nessa comparação (Também não encontrei uma documentação que explique mais sobre o IfStatementTree, o máximo que encontrei foi [isso](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java/java-squid/2.8/org/sonar/plugins/java/api/tree/IfStatementTree.java)).

Alguém poderia por gentileza me ajudar com esta questão ou me apontar para algum conteúdo que tenha mais informações?

Desde já, muito obrigado pela atenção!